# Why do angular2-NativeScript applications need to rebuild to update CSS

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

As the question says why do I have to rebuild the whole app(or uninstall the app from my phone/emulator) to see changes on CSS.
Is there a solid reason this has to be done ? Is there a way, or something intended in the future for this issue?

Comment: You can use livesync for that try - tns livesync android --watch. Can you share some sort of code you are trying.